# CodeIgniter 2.x Back-end and Front-end management

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I saw many threads, articles and some really clever posts concerning about layouts for both backend and frontend approach on the same website.

I would like to hear your feedbacks (pros and cons) about each type of introduced front/backend management who had a real experience with codeigniter:

1. Controller-separated section

   ```
   ./web/system/...
   ./web/application
        /application/controllers/* (config/controllers/hooks/models/views...)
        /application/controllers/admin/* (config/controllers/hooks/models/views...)
   ```
2. Application type of cms

   ```
   ./web/system/...
   ./web/front/* (config/controllers/hooks/models/views...)
   ./web/admin/* (config/controllers/hooks/models/views...)
   ```
3. Sub-application

   ```
   ./web/system/...
   ./web/application
        /application/admin/controllers/* (config/controllers/hooks/models/views...)
        /application/front/controllers/* (config/controllers/hooks/models/views...)
   ```

Thanks for your suggestions and tips.

Comment: Question - let's say If i would use 3rd method (sub-application), could i access admin's controller/models from front app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we did for our application was create a structure like so:

The application folder was divided into three subfolders 
backend
frontend
common

This helped us better structure our resources so that when something goes wrong in the backend we do not need to sift through frontend files, for instance.

Comment: This sounds good, didn't even thinking about this 3-way app structure. Is there any complications about it ?

Comment: We had to really think it through before implementing because we were moving an existing CI project with conventional design to this new structure. But after the initial changes, it works like a charm.We are loosely coupling our resources so in the future we might remove the `common` folder and have copies (if needed) inside `backend` and `frontend`. This way, if we need to say move the backend application to a separate server for instance, it becomes easier.